# Can I use a Firestore snapshot listener to listen to changes only in cache?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As of right now, I want to use Firestore's get functions with document cursors to paginate my data. However, I would like to have some way of locally updating the items in a query result when they are changed locally on the device. Ideally, if there is some way to use a snapshot listener to only listen to changes from the cache, then I would be able to drastically reduce the number of total reads because I only need to fetch the first (10? or whatever limit you set) documents from the server rather than the whole collection which, if user base grows, could be 1000+ documents potentially. I'm leaning towards probably having to use some custom cache implementation of my own, but that just seems redundant when Firestore already offers caching abilities. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `onSnapshot` listeners and [disable network](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Firestore#disablenetworkcompletion:) for the Firestore client that should indeed be possible.

Just keep in mind that the local cache of Firestore does not use the same indexing strategy as the server-side implementation, and that the performance guarantees that you commonly see for Firestore only apply to the server-side. Typically: performance will initially be good, but gets worse if you stay offline longer.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that disabling and enabling the network is an app-wide procedure? So I couldn't do that with just one or two snapshot listeners @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Correct, that is indeed a setting for the entire app. You can prevent per collection, by simply not attaching listeners and forcing the `get()` to come from the cache: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/GetOptions-class.html

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I think my initial plan was trying to use the get requests for retrieving server data and then using the listener to update a list of items if I edit one of those items. It may be easier in this case to actually use my own custom cache implementation instead, as I believe that I can add local listeners for each item so that if it changes in the cache, it will be updated on the device. The other alternative is using a get(source: cache) call every time I update an item locally, but that doesn't seem like a good solution. Thank you though! @FrankvanPuffelen